# How to check the array values in where condition?

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Hi friends i have a small idea in array so please help me!!!

Here i have **3 tables**
     1. tbl_prescription
     2. tbl_pre_medi
     3. tbl_stock

`tbl_stock` is used to keep the stock of medicine

```
m_id   on_hand    returned  
111    600        0  
222    600        0
```

`on_hand` is current stock **returned** is selling medicine ,we select some medicine  that quantity add to returned and subtract from on_hand

`tbl_prescription` is used to store the buy medicical data and `tbl_pre_medi` is store the quantity and medicine name that insert by an array

`tbl_prescription`

```
prscrptn_id   p_opno    p_family   p_patient   p_date  
1             1002      2          5           2017-08-04  
2             1003      2          3           2017-08-04
```

`tbl_pre_medi`

```
med_prscrptn_id   medi_id   medi_qunty  
1                 111       4  
1                 222       2  
2                 222       5
```

here my data are inserted, but how to tbl_stock check with tbl_pre_medi -this table data are in array how to check array value in where condition?

**my controller**

```
$pid=$this->input->post('pid');
$data = array(
              'prscrptn_id' =>$pid,
              'p_opno' =>$this->input->post('opno'),
              'p_family' =>$this->input->post('family'),
              'p_patient' =>$this->input->post('member'),
              'p_date' =>$this->input->post('date')
             );
$form_data=$this->input->post();
$medicine=$form_data['medi_name'];
$qunty=$form_data['qty_med'];
$result=$this->Prescription_model->insert_prscrptn($form_data,$data,$pid);
```

**my model**

```
public function insert_prscrptn($form_data,$data,$pid)
    {
        $medicine=$form_data['medi_name'];
        $qunty=$form_data['qty_med'];

        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('tbl_stock');
        $this->db->where('m_id',$medicine);
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();

        $insert_prscrpt=[];
        foreach($medicine as $key => $value)
        {
            $insert_prscrpt[$key]=
            array(
            'medi_id'=>$medicine[$key],
            'medi_qunty'=>$qunty[$key],
            'med_prscrptn_id'=>$pid
            );  
        }


        $query1=$this->db->insert('tbl_prescription',$data);
        $query=$this->db->insert_batch('tbl_pre_medi', $insert_prscrpt);
        return $query;
    }
```

how to check array value in where condition ?
any one help me!!!
thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is still not clear what you want to check?

Comment: $medicine check to tbl_stock m_id and add quantity to returen and subtract from on_ hand u see the query " /***** here i check the condition how?*******/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `where_in` clause instead of `where` for array in codeigniter, like mentioned below.

```
$this->db->where('meb_id',$medicine);
```

**Replace**

```
$this->db->where_in('meb_id', $medicine);
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: how to reduce the quantity in stock _tbl ?

Comment: On which specific action you want to reduce quantity in stock_tbl.?

Comment: what is difference between                 "array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (2) { ["m_id"]=> string(3) "111" ["on_hand"]=> string(3) "494" } }"     and           " array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["medi_id"]=> string(3) "111" ["medi_qunty"]=> string(2) "20" ["med_prscrptn_id"]=> string(1) "2" } }"

Comment: Humm it seems like your first array is standard object and second one is array. Standard object you can get item with `->` operator like `$array->item` while in array you can get item with `$array['item']`.